# What is the most efficient way to determine length of a text file?

Tags: java, performance, arraylist, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I have a data file which is comprised of rows of data, newline separated. I need to read the contents of the file into an array of Strings, and I would like to efficiently create the array at the correct size. Is it most efficient to

1. Use an ArrayList,
2. Scan through the file using BufferedReader, marking the start, counting lines and then reseting back to the mark,
   or
3. ???

Comment: What size of file are we talking about?

Comment: A few hundred lines, but I would like an answer for any size file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an `ArrayList` (your option #1). Read in your text file line by line with `BufferedReader`'s `readLine()` method. It's simple, efficient and maintainable.

Comment: In Java 7 a new package and class is introduced, java.nio.file.Files:  `List<String> allLines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename), Charset.forName("iso-8859-1"));`

Comment: @Kennet, is there any performance improvement for this approach

Comment: I have not tested that. But it's a lot shorter to write than what I usually tend to do.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the size of file and what kind of efficiency you need:

1. ArrayList is a simple and efficient option. Just create a new instance and add Strings from BufferedReader one by one. Then call toArray() on this list.
2. Read the whole file as string and split it manually (I believe more efficient) or with regexp split provided by java.lang.String into array of strings. If you do that manually, you can count number of "\r\n" symbols and create an array of the exact size (i.e. you'll save array-list re-allocations).

Answer (score 2):

You can use an ArrayList and use the following methods for optimize the size  of it:

- trimToSize: Trims the capacity of this ArrayList instance to be the list's current size. An application can use this operation to minimize the storage of an ArrayList instance.
- ensureCapacity:Increases the capacity of this ArrayList instance, if necessary, to ensure that it can hold at least the number of elements specified by the minimum capacity argument.

Additionally if you know the average size of each line, you can try to determine the size of array in base to lenght of file (file_size / line_avg_size).

Answer (score 2):

[ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is more preferable to your second one.

I do not want to reinvent the wheel with my own code when proven solution is there.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is to read in the whole file with one operation. This is because disk IO is usually relatively slow, and will likely be the slowest part of your application. Read the whole file into a big string and then [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) it on the new line token ('\n'). This is probably the easiest, and most efficient way to do this. Split() will produce an array of strings with the data for you.

Comment: You could try File.readFileToString: http://commons.apache.org/io/api-1.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#readFileToString%28java.io.File%29

Answer (score 1):

Create a writer which counts the number of characters written and use that to wrap your OutputStreamWriter.

**Note:** The correct way to save text to a file is:

`new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter( new FileOutputStream( file ), encoding ) ) );`

The encoding is important; it's usually "UTF-8".

This chain gives you two places where you can inject your wrapper: You can wrap the writer to get the number of characters or the inner `OutputStream` to get bytes written.

Answer (score 0):

3 : use Scanner (Since 1.5) : the lazy (but malicious) programmer tool with all options needed for String scanning purpose and valid for all files.

Comment: Scanner does not provide any methods to readily determine the length of a file.

Comment: @trav1th : because it do not load file in memory, for any file size it is a good tool (no 'heap space' problem). In Java 7 nio.file.Files.size(PathOfFile) give the size among others usefull methods. It is also a response to 3 ??? that can suggest that the first approch is not the most appropriate.